# Цикл внутри потока. С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, visual-c++, c++11

Здравствуйте!

Используеться стандарт С++11, и библиотека `<thread>`.

Есть поток который запускаеться в "фоновом" режиме `thread.detach()`. внутри етого потока есть функция `setWallpaper(bool status)` с бесконечным циклом:

```
setWallpaper(bool status) {
   if(!status) {
       MessageBox(NULL, status, L"STOP", MB_OK);
   }
   while (status) {
       PVOID path = getPath(rand() % 8 + 1);
       SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
       Sleep(min * 1000);
    }
}
```

Если обратиться к етой функции и передать значение переменной `false`, то цикл все еще работает, но должна бы завершиться. Почему так не пойму. Подскажете? Как остановить/завершить цикл? Спасибо)

Comment: Вы передаете переменную по значению. Сколько не меняй ее в других местах, внутри функции она не поменяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал по своему, вроде работает, мне достаточно :)

`status` и `interval` в глобальном скоупе.

Да, знаю что не правильно, но мне сойдёт)

```
bool status = true;
int interval = 1;



void startNewThread(int interval) {
    thread newThread(setWallpaper, &status, interval);
    newThread.detach();
};

int setWallpaper(bool *status, int interval) {
   while (true) {
      if (*status == false) return 0;
      wstring path = getPath();
      SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)path.c_str(), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(interval));
   }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку "stop":

```
bool *ptrStatus = &status;
*ptrStatus = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `std::future` для ожидания и сигнализации о завершении:

```
void setWallpaper(std::future<void> stop) {
   auto period = std::chrono::seconds(min);
   do {
       PVOID path = getPath(rand() % 8 + 1);
       SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
   } while (stop.wait_for(period) != std::future_status::ready);
}
```

Запуск:

```
std::promise<void> stop;
std::thread(setWallpaper, stop.get_future()).detach();

// Остановка:
stop.set_value();
```

Comment: `error C2280: "std::future<void>::future(const std::future<void> &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию`

Answer (score 0):

При втором вызове функции предыдущий вызов не завершается по причине того, что в нем бесконечный цикл.